# Ado's theorem and the reduction to positive characteristic

Tags: lo.logic, lie-algebras, model-theory, characteristic-p

**The synopsis: proofs of Ado theorem in positive characteristic are simple, and in characteristic $0$ are difficult. Can one infer the characteristic $0$ case from the positive characteristic case?**

### The context

Ado's theorem ensures that any finite-dimensional Lie algebra has a faithful representation:

*Let $K$ be an arbitrary field and $\frak g$ a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $K$. Then there exists an injective homomorphism of Lie algebras ${\frak g}\to {\frak gl}(n,K)$ for some natural number $n$.*

Its proof for $K$ of characteristic $0$ is, perhaps unexpectedly, quite involved and requires the prior development of much of the structural theory.

On the other hand, the characteristic $p$ case is quite simple modulo the Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem: the naive idea of using the PBW embedding to the universal enveloping algebra actually works out after taking a suitable quotient. Here is a sketch of the argument (due to Jacobson):

1. In $U(\frak g)$ one has $ad_x^my=\sum_{i=0}^m (-1)^i \binom{m}{i} x^iyx^{m-i}$ and if $m=p$ then each $\binom{p}{i}=0$ unless $i=0,p$. Thus $ad_x^p y=ad_{x^p} y$ and hence $ad_x^{p ^i}y=ad_{x^{p ^i}} y$ for any $i$.
2. Let $Q(X)$ be a minimal polynomial of $ad_x$, so $Q(ad_x)=0$. By euclidean division $X^{p^i}=Q(X)U_i(X)+R_i(X)$, where $\deg R_i<\deg Q\le \dim \frak g$. Since the space of polynomials of degree $<\dim \frak g$ has dimension $\dim \frak g$ there is a nontrivial linear combination $\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g} \lambda_iR_i(X)=0$ and hence $Q(X)\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g}\lambda_iU_i(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g}\lambda_iX^{p^i}$. In particular, $ad_x$ is annihilated by  $\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g}\lambda_iX^{p^i}$.
3. By combining Step 1 and Step 2 one obtains $\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g}\lambda_i ad_x^{p^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g}\lambda_i ad_{x^{p^i}}=ad_{\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g} \lambda_ix^{p^i}}=0$. In other words, $\sum_{i=0}^{\dim \frak g}\lambda_ix^{p^i}$ is central in $U(\frak g)$. Thus for any $x_i$ from some basis of $\frak g$ one has a decomposition $x_i^{p^{n_i}}=z_i+P_i(x_i)$ where $z_i$ is central and $\deg P_i<p^{n_i}$, where $n_i\le \dim \frak g$.
4. Let $I\subset U(\frak g)$ be an ideal generated by all $z_i$ from the previous step. By PBW $x_1^{k_1}\dots x_{\dim \frak g}^{k_{\dim \frak g}}$ is a basis of $U(\frak g)$. The elements of the form $\bar x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots \bar x_{\dim \frak g}^{\alpha_{\dim \frak g}}$ where $\alpha_i<p^{n_i}$ make up a basis of $U({\frak g})/I$. Indeed, they span everything because if some $\alpha_i\ge p^{n_i}$, then using the decomposition $x_i^{p^{n_i}}=z_i+P_i(x_i)$ we can rewrite the monomial as a sum of monomials in which $\bar x_i$ occurs with degree $<\alpha_i$. Linear independence obviously follows from the linear independence of $x_1^{k_1}\dots x_{\dim \frak g}^{k_{\dim \frak g}}$ in $U(\frak g)$.
   So $U({\frak g})/I$ is an associative algebra of dimension $\le (p^{\dim(\frak g)})^{\dim \frak g}$.
5. Then, as usual, embed $U({\frak g})/I$ to ${\frak{gl}}(U({\frak g})/I)$ using its action on itself by right multiplication. Note that the dimension of representation thus obtained is $\le p^{2\cdot\dim^2(\frak g)}$.

Another, more compact, way to phrase this is to introduce the notion of a [restricted Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Lie_algebra), show that there is the corresponding version of PBW for restricted universal enveloping algebras, which are always finite-dimensional, and to notice that any Lie algebra admits an embedding into a f.d. restricted Lie algebra.

### The question

***Is there a proof of Ado theorem (assuming algebraic closedness, if inevitable) by reduction to the positive characteristic case?***

The first thing that comes to mind is to use the fact that the ultraproduct of all prime algebraically closed fields is elementary equivalent to the field of complex numbers: $\text{ulim}_{p\to\infty}\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p\cong\mathbb C$. The statement about a field
*“Each $m$-dimensional Lie algebra over me has a faithful representation of dimension $n$”* is a first order sentence in the language of fields (actually an algebraic condition), but unfortunately the dimensions of faithful representations given by Jacobson's characteristic $p$ proof grow indefinitely with $p$. On the other hand the sentence  *“Each $m$-dimensional Lie algebra over me has a finite-dimensional faithful representation”* does not seem like a first-order sentence in $ACF_0$.

I hope that there might be some smarter choice of the language, theory and coding, which could rescue this (“model theoretic”) approach.

I am aware of the existence of other “reduction to char. $p$” methods in mathematics (starting with the Hensel lemma!) so would love to know if any of them apply here.

Comment: The Lie algebra with basis $A,B,C$ and relations $[A,B]=C, [A,C]=[B,C]=0$ has, in each characteristic $p$, faithful finite-dimensional representations where $C$ acts by the scalar $1 $ (on the ring $k[x]/(x^p)$ where $A$ acts by multiplication by $x$, $B$ differentiation by $x$, and $C$ acts by $1$) but its only finite-dimensional representations in characteristic $0$ have $C$ nilpotent. So any model-theoretic method would have to break after placing even mild conditions on the representation